# Need to hide button

Tags: acumatica

We have one button in the Sales Order screen, which is created in another customization package, now how i can access and hide it. I added the .dll of that customization package into my project as the reference but I could not able to access the button. How we can access it.

Comment: Please add a  Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I think we can answer without the MCVE :)

Comment: I'm a bit short on time to test but I'm almost certain Runtime customization are part of the same compilation unit so they would be visible to each other. From memory I think if the second customization is Runtime code it can pick up references (adjust Level in customizations screen though) because it's dynamically compiled. If both customizations are libraries I would advise to create a third shared libraries with the shared types as libraries need to be statically compiled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do not wish to add reference of another customization package's DLL, you can consider following approach as well.

```cs
if (Base.Actions["SomeAction"] != null)
{
    Base.Actions["SomeAction"].SetVisible(false);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much DChhapgar :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `PXGraph.GetExtension<T>()` method for getting the extension of the `SalesOrderEntry` and access added action from it. Below is example of code how to do it:

```
protected void SOOrder_RowSelected(PXCache sende,PXRowSelectedEventArg e,PXRowSelected baseMethod)
{
   baseMethod?.Invoke(sender,e);
   if(e.Row is SOOrder row)
   {
       var grExt=this.Base.GetExtension<SOOrderEntryExtNAME>();
       grExt.SomeAction.SetVisible(false);
   }
}
```